# Shared Project for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-libraries

I have two ASP.NET web projects and they share a lot of images and JavaScript files. I tried to create a shared project and linking it into both ASP.NET *csproj* files:

```
<Import Project="..\Shared\Shared.projitems" Label="Shared" />
```

But images inside the shared project are not found during debugging with IIS (Browsers "image not found" image is displayed). But Visual Studio recognized them and showing the image files in IntelliSense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You still can bundle resources with project and distribute it, but you nee to create nuget package.

1. create project
2. make nuget package
3. publish it to private feed (e.g. myget.org)
4. add reference to your feed from client projects

PS: Only content of folder 'Content' included in nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the speculative answer, but hopefully this will help someone;

This is a struggle I'm currently facing too (which is concerning, as nearly two years have passed with barely a mention).

I have also had to manually add the Import line to each solution as it appears you have.

I think the issue is with the inbuilt debugger not knowing how to serve the files properly. If you **deploy the compiled solution to any instance of IIS** it appears to work correctly.

I am experimenting with the inbuilt debugger to see if I can get it to work, but am quite confident I'll have to **use a local IIS instance moving forward**.

Shared projects provide invaluable functionality, so it's a shame it's still not natively supported.

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the day your images have to actually be somewhere, you can't just reference them from another project. It would work if this other project was hosted in IIS, given a domain, and you referenced the images from this domain. Perhaps call it your CDN.

When you reference a project to get at  classes etc, the project is bundled up in to a dll and packaged along with the main project. Images, js files etc can't be bundled in to a dll, and will not be copied across to your project.

Comment: But it  is a shared project, not a class library. That means all files will copied to the referencing project. If you look at a Windows/WP JavaScript App it works.